# SASS: Using @extend with @use

Tags: sass, extend

I have the two following files:

```
main.scss
|- base
|  |- _typography.scss
```

The `_typography.scss` file contains:

```
$font-family: Roboto;

%typo-button{
    font-family: $font-family;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Now I am triying to `@extend` a class in `main.scss` with the placeholder `%typo-button.`

```
@use 'base/typography';

.button{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 12px 0px;
    @extend typography.%typo-button;
}
```

The following error is thrown:

```
Error: Expected identifier.
│     @extend typography.%typo-button;
```

So what is the correct syntax to use `@extend` with `@use`? Using `@use` with a `@mixin` is no problem, e.g.`@include typography.my-mixin()`. But I would like to use `@extend` instead of mixins in some cases.

Answer (score 15):

Namespace prefixes are not necessary on `@extends` - only on functions, mixins, and variables. Remove `typography.` and it should work:

```
@use 'base/typography';

.button{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 12px 0px;
    @extend %typo-button;
}
```

(The upstream limitation mentioned above means that the "typography" module can't extend anything inside the "main" module that uses it – but selectors in "main" *can* extend selectors in "typography".)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two ways for you to solve this problem:

the first is to use `@mixin` instead of `%typo-button` and `@include typography.typo-button` instead of `@extend typography.typo-button`

OR

you need to `@use '../main'` inside of **_typography.scss** to have access to `%typo-button` (I think that is what is meant by the docs when they say

> extension will only affect style rules written in upstream modules—that is, modules that are loaded by that stylesheet using the @use rule or the @forward rule, modules loaded by those modules, and so on

here https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend#extension-scope)

UPDATE:
the second option is not correct per Miriam. See her answer to correctly use @extend.